# How to solve gson.fromJson() have error in android

Tags: android, gson

Now I am new to gson. I have to parse large json file for my android project.
I search on the internet to get good performance. Then, I found gson.
But I have an error. I don't know what did I wrong. What should I fix?

Answer (score 0):

when we pass JsonReader then we need to define the type also

method signature

```
public <T> T fromJson(JsonReader reader,
                  Type typeOfT)
           throws JsonIOException,
                  JsonSyntaxException
```

so change something like this

```
 Type type = new TypeToken<City>(){}.getType();

 City city = gson.fromJson(jsonReader,type);
```

[docs](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.reflect.Type-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still got the same error "Cannot resolve method(....,java.lang.reflect.Type)"

Comment: If possible get the json string from the reader and pass it to the fromJson

Comment: I read inputstream with BufferedReader and then I use String builder to get json String. But the main problem to performance is builder.toString() took so long. So I want to use some other ways. If you have any suggest, please tell me which library should i use to parse large json.